# make inline transfer contract and using it on jungle testnet

Tags: smart-contract, testnet, inline-action, balances

hello everyone i am faceing a problem on jungle testnet i am trying to make a inline transfer
but i got this error after i work with the api_endpoint
the code is

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio.token/eosio.token.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract("test")]] test : public contract{
    private:

        void make_transfer(name from,name to,asset quantity,string memo)
        {
            token::transfer_action do_transfer("eosio.token"_n,{from,"active"_n});
            do_transfer.send(from,to,quantity,memo);
        }

    public:
        test(name receiver,name code,datastream <const char *> ds):contract(receiver,code,ds){}

        [[eosio::action]]
        void trade(name from,name mid,name to,asset fromasset,asset toasset,string memo)
        {
            make_transfer(from,mid,fromasset,memo);
            make_transfer(mid,to,toasset,memo);

        }
};
```

> cleos -u http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80 push action jungledex151 trade '["jungledexts1","jungledex151","jungledexts2","10.0000 EOS","10.0000 JUNGLE","test"]' -p jungledexts1@active -p jungledex151@active 
>   Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
>   Error Details:
>   assertion failure with message: no balance object found
>   pending console output:

Answer (score 0):

Check whether jungledexts1 doesn't have EOS or jungledex151 doesn't have JUNGLE.